# wp_list_categories pagination

Tags: pagination, categories

I was wondering if I can paginate wp_list_categories? I had a go with paginate_links but no luck. Or is there a good workaround? Thank you!!

```
<?php   $orderby = 'name';
    $show_count = 0;
    $pad_counts = 0;
    $hierarchical = 1;
    $taxonomy = 'categories';
    $title = '';
    $exclude = '16';

    $args = array(
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'show_count' => $show_count,
    'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'title_li' => $title,
    'exclude' => $exclude,
    'hide_empty' => 0
    );
    ?>
    <ul class="resourcelist">
    <?php wp_list_categories($args); ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, after no luck with wp_list_categories, I resorted to get_categories to get the pagination working. I hope this helps someone.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categories',
            'orderby' => 'term_group',
            'hide_empty' => 0,
            'hierarchical' => 1,
            'exclude' => '16',
            'parent' => '0',
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    $numOfItems = 60;
    $page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
    $to = $page * $numOfItems;
    $current = $to - $numOfItems;
    $total = sizeof($categories);

            echo '<ul class="content">';

    for ($i=$current; $i<$to; ++$i) {

        $category = $categories[$i];

        if ($category->name) { echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link($category->slug, 'categories') . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a></li>';}

    }

            echo '</ul>';

    unset($category);
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
        'format' => '',
        'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
        'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
        'total' => ceil($total / $numOfItems),
        'current' => $page
    ));

    ?>
```

Comment: you need to change the $numOfItems to get your desired number of items per page, currently it is set to 60.